# PHP Imagick - display first slice of mutli image TIFF

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to display the first slice of a multi image TIFF within my HTML page. Therefore, I'm trying to use Imagemagick to somehow convert the TIFF to a widely supported format like JPG or PNG. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php 
$im = new imagick('my_image.tif');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
ob_start();
$thumbnail = $im->getImageBlob();
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($thumbnail)."' />";

 ?>
```

This code works fine when reading a JPG file - but for TIFF files, this displays something - but not the content of my TIFF file. I guess I have to submit the TIFF-files properties, just like when I'm creating them? The TIFF-file is created in a C programm like that:

```
 TIFF* tif;
 tif = TIFFOpen(filename, "w");
 TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, columns);
 TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, rows);
 TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
 TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 32);
 TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT, SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP);

 for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     TIFFWriteScanline(tif, &data[i * columns], i, 0);

 TIFFWriteDirectory(tif);
 TIFFClose(tif);
```

How can I convert this properly to be shown on my webpage? Additionally, how can I chose which of the images to be shown? Ideally, the user of the webpage would be able to scroll through the slices of the TIFF file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your creating the TIFF images from C, be sure the following tags are defined, or at least set to a default value.

- `TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH`
- `TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH`
- `TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION`
- `TIFFTAG_FILLORDER`
- `TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG`
- `TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL`
- `TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE`
- `TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT`
- `TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE`
- `TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE`
- `TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC`

See the header check in the [`coders/tiff.c`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/ImageMagick-6/coders/tiff.c#L1205) to ensure tiff-file generation would be valid for ImageMagick use.

I can only suggest creating a quick header validation / dump program in C to discover which header is not defaulting correctly, and adjust the TIFF generation program.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the image can now be displayed. Unfortunatelly, the grayscale of the image is not displayed correctly. Please check this link: [link](http://postimg.org/image/3w6voyy39/) The upper row shows the wrongly displayed browser output, the lower row shows the way it looks in FIJI. Playing around with `TIFFTAG_MINSAMPLEVALUE` and `TIFFTAG_MAXSAMPLEVALUE` did not change the output...

Comment: Can't help without seeing data, but I would guess it's a data-type issue that loses integer precision. @MarkSetchell's answer would help identifying what ImageMagick sees

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like ImageMagick only takes the float values between 0 and 1 and stretches them from 0 to 255. After normalizing my TIFF-files, it works fine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi-page TIFF, you can extract a specific page by placing the page number (indexed from zero) in square brackets after the filename, so for the first two pages:

```
convert multipage.tif[0] page1.jpg
convert multipage.tif[1] page2.jpg
```

I can't remember the easy way to get the number of pages, but you can run this and count the number of lines till I do :-)

```
identify multipage.tif
multipage.tif[0] TIFF 1x1 1x1+0+0 16-bit sRGB 830B 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.tif[1] TIFF 1x1 1x1+0+0 16-bit sRGB 830B 0.000u 0:00.000
multipage.tif[2] TIFF 1x1 1x1+0+0 16-bit sRGB 830B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

That one has 3 pages, numbered 0-2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to convert the tif to a different format in the terminal using the `convert` command. Unfortunatelly, I get an error message stating `convert: improper image header 'test.tif' @ error/tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1218`. The TIFF files work fine in ImageJ. Any idea which property might be missing/wrong for imagick?

Comment: Sorry - it's kind of hard without seeing your image and I am no great expert on TIFFs anyway. Maybe you could try `TiffTagViewer` or some such to analyse your file :-(